# How to find the max and min from a string in python?

Tags: python, if-statement, for-loop, max, min

This is my current program. It's outputting the incorrect max and min. What is missing from my if statement?

```
def palin():
  max = 0
  min = 50
  numbers = "23","3","4","6","10"
  for x in numbers:

    if x>max:
      max=x
    if x<min:
      min=x

  print max
  print min
```

Comment: numbers = (23,3,4,6,10)

Comment: Just a side note, you can use `min_val = float('inf')` and `max_val = float('-inf')` to handle a much larger range of numbers. Also note, you're overshadowing two built-in functions that can help you do what you want to do very easily!

Answer (score 10):

When you do string comparisons or try to use `min()`, `max()` with strings, you are actually maintaining alphabetical ordering:

```
>>> sorted(numbers)
['10', '23', '3', '4', '6']
```

This is why a lot of the [built-in](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max) Python functions that rely on positional comparison support the [`key`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max) argument:

```
>>> numbers
('23', '3', '4', '6', '10')
>>> sorted(numbers, key=int)
['3', '4', '6', '10', '23']
>>> min(numbers, key=int)
'3'
>>> max(numbers, key=int)
'23'
```

Answer (score 2):

Your numbers are strings. First convert them to integers:

```
numbers = [int(num) for num in numbers]
```

---

```
def palin():
  max = 0
  min = 50
  numbers = "23","3","4","6","10"
  numbers = [int(num) for num in numbers]
  for x in numbers:

    if x>max:
      max=x
    if x<min:
      min=x

  print max
  print min
```

Answer (score 1):

Many common actions in python have related `built-in` functions or related modules/packages.

In this case `max()` and `min()` are your friends.

```
str_numbers = ("23", "3", "4", "6", "10")
numbers = [int(n) for n in str_numbers ]  # convert to integers
max_value = max(numbers)
min_value = min(numbers)
```

`max()` and `min()` also support the use of generator expressions, so you can do the conversion in the function itself:

```
str_numbers = ("23", "3", "4", "6", "10")
max_value = max(int(n) for n in str_numbers)
min_value = min(int(n) for n in str_numbers)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed Numpy, you can get the result easily.

```
import numpy as np

numbers = ["23","3","4","6","10"]
numbers = [int(n) for n in numbers]
numpy_array = np.array(numbers)
print 'Max:  ', numpy_array.max()
print 'Min:  ', numpy_array.min()
print 'Mean: ', numpy_array.mean()
```